# How to manipulate large arrays R

Tags: r, data-manipulation, rbind

I have a large array with dimensions `data[1:10,1:50,1:1000]`. I would like to swap out the 5th row of all the matrices with new data with the dimensions `new_data[1,1:50,1:1000]`.

So far I have tried to pull the array apart and put it back together:

```
data1<-data[1:4,1:50,1:1000]
data2<-data[6:10,1:50,1:1000]

combined_data<-rbind(data1,new_data,data2)
```

However `rbind` doesn't seem to be appropriate here and returns a large matrix rather than a large array with `dimensions[1:10,1:50,1:1000]`

On request here is a simple example:

```
vec1<-1:4
vec2<-c(1,2,2,4,1,2,2,4)
data_array<-array(c(vec1,vec2),dim=c(4,3,10))
data_array[,,1] # visualizing one of the 10 matrix - say they error is in row 3 where we would expect all 3s  


new_data<-array(c(3,3,3),dim=c(1,3,10))
new_data[,,1] # correct data that we want to swap into row 3 of all the matrices 

array2<-data_array[1:2,,] #correct data from original array 
array3<-array(data_array[4,,],dim=c(1,3,10)) #correct data from original array

combined_data <- rbind(array2,new_data,array3) # attempting to combine and new_data into the correct row
```

However this results in a data with the dimensions [1:3,1:60], where I am aiming for the exact same dimensions as the original data_array ([1:4,1:3,1:10]) but with the new_data swapped in at row 3 of each matrix

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with abind from "abind" package.

```
library(abind)
array4 <- abind(array2,new_data,along=1) 
final_data <- abind(array4,array3,along=1)
```

The reference is as follows:

[http://math.furman.edu/~dcs/courses/math47/R/library/abind/html/abind.html](http://math.furman.edu/%7Edcs/courses/math47/R/library/abind/html/abind.html)

Comment: If anyone wants to know the final solution I used was : array4<-abind(array2,new_data,along=1)
final_data<-abind(array4,array3,along=1)

Comment: I downvoted, because it's not an answer. Suggesting a documentation page from which somebody could figure out an answer is a comment. @AdSad's comment above is ironically an answer. If you edited that bit of code in to show how `abind` works, I'd be happy to remove the downvote, and in fact give an upvote.

Comment: Understood, and did accordingly @thelatemail

Answer (score 0):

Since an array is really just a vector with dimensions, you can replace every 4th value (the number of rows in each stratum), starting at the 3rd value (the row you want to replace), with the `new_data`

```
data_array[seq(3, by=dim(data_array)[1], to=length(data_array))] <- new_data
data_array

#, , 1
#
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    1    1
#[2,]    2    2    2
#[3,]    3    3    3
#[4,]    4    4    4
#
#, , 2
#
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    1    1
#[2,]    2    2    2
#[3,]    3    3    3
#[4,]    4    4    4
#...
```